# How can I run a new terminal with bash, but with a custom bashrc?

Tags: bash, terminal, bashrc

I open a new terminal with `bash` as follows.

```
gnome-terminal -x bash
gnome-terminal -e bash
gnome-terminal -- bash
```

Somewhere I read that to use a custom BASH RC file, you have to run:

```
bash --login <custom_rc>
```

I'm not sure if it works, but the problem is that it doesn't leave the interpreter open like with the previous commands. I have also tried with:

```
bash -c "source <custom_rc>"
```

But the same thing happens, after reading the configuration closes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the manual, the `--rcfile` switch accomplishes the objective in interactive mode.

> --rcfile file
>
> Execute commands from file instead of the standard personal initialization file
>   ~/.bashrc if the shell is interactive

It seems we can infer that the environment variable, `BASH_ENV`, accomplishes the same  in non-interactive mode.

> BASH_ENV
>
> If this parameter is set when bash is executing a shell script, its value is interpreted as a filename  containing commands to initialize the shell, as in ~/.bashrc. [...]